# Qual extensão do PHP devo usar com o SQL Server 2000?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Estou tentando conectar ao banco de dados do SQL Server 2000 usando PHP PDO SQLSRV, porém quando acesso a **index** me retorna o `catch()` com o seguinte erro

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Native Client 11.0 does not support connections to SQL Server 2000 or earlier versions.

Alguma dica de como posso resolver?

Comment: Veja se [isso te ajuda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783613/how-to-connect-to-mssql-2000-from-php-5-3-and-up).

Comment: Qual versão do php está usando?

Comment: 5.4.8 a versão do meu PHP

Comment: Uma tentativa de remediar é usar o driver do odbc para PDO.

Comment: Vou tentar resolver com o driver odbc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente essa versão do SQL Server Native Client não funciona com o SQL.  Server 2000.

Você precisa utilizar o Microsoft Drivers 2.0 for PHP for SQL Server nesse caso e o Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client.

Entretanto, para utilizar a versão 2.0, você precisa usar no **máximo** o PHP 5.3. Use essa tabela como comparação:

```
| Versão do Driver | Versão do PHP  | Versão SQL Server |
|------------------|----------------|-------------------|
| 3.2              | 5.4, 5.5 e 5.6 | 2005+             |
| 3.1              | 5.4 e 5.5      | 2005+             |
| 3                | 5.3 e 5.4      | 2005+             |
| 2                | 5.2 e 5.3      | 2000+             |
```

Mais informações [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: E pra SQL Server 2008 ? não tem na lista no site da microsoft

Comment: Resolvi usando o link que você mandou, obrigado, qualquer coisa abro outra pergunta.

Comment: Então é do 2005 pra frente :)
O 2008 deve funcionar